# xpath not working in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the below xml string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Structure>
   <LongUnsigned value="142794"/>
   <OctetString value="07E2051E030F1E0404800000"/>
   <Structure>
      <OctetString value="07E2051E030F1E0404800000"/>
      <OctetString value="66574536387"/>
      <Array>
         <Structure><OctetString value="0000000000000001"/><OctetString value="9889892347"/></Structure>
         <Structure><OctetString value="00098347586768574"/><OctetString value="6283046502"/></Structure>
         <Structure><OctetString value="0000011000000001"/><OctetString value="899734729847586"/></Structure>
      </Array>
   </Structure>
</Structure>
```

I am using the below xpath but it always returns an empty string.

```
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        try {
            String eval = xPath.evaluate("//Structure/Structure/Array", new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            System.out.println("Eval:" + eval);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried running this xpath online and it seems to work just fine. What am i missing in Java that makes it not work as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't the context be a `Document` node?  Are you sure it is correct to use an `InputSource` as the context?

Comment: Your xml doesn’t contain any text data. You need to call the 3-argument version of evaluate and pass XPathConstants.NODESET or XPathConstants.NODE as the last argument.

Comment: @JimGarrison it could be either. I tried with both `Document` and `InputSource` as a string. The string was actually generated from a `Document` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression selects an element node, not a string. So you need to ask for the result to be returned as a NODESET.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java reading XML but your `XPath` should be something like this:

```
/Structure/Structure/Array/Stucture/OctetString/@value
```

This will start at the root-node `<Structure>`, move down to the nested `<Structure>`, further down to `<Array>`, then to the nested `<OctetString>` elements to fetch their `value` attribute.

Your expression `//Structure/Structure/Array` starts at **any** `<Structure>` (due to the `//`) and tries to read the value of `<Array>`, but there is no value, just deeper nodes...

Comment: an upvote for you. The other answer by Michael Kay was exactly what i intended to do.